# Как правильно организовать многопоток в моем случае?

Tags: c#

Есть такой простой Сниппет:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 30, p => {
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(p*500);
  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(p));
});
```

По логике на выходе мы должны видеть последовательность: 0,1,2,3...28,29
А сам скрипт по времени должен занимать 15 секунд.
Но на выходе мы получаем последовательность этих чисел вперемешку.
Что не так? как правильно сделать?

Comment: оно и работает в многопотоке, так как Вы и хотели, результат об этом даже говорит

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Почему последовательность? Суть многопоточности в том и заключается, что потоки выполняются *параллельно*, то есть *одновременно*. Соответственно, каждый поток выводит свои данные, которые перемешиваются с данными другого потока.

Почему 15 секунд? Во-первых, запуск потока занимает время (сколько именно - предсказать нельзя). Даже если берётся готовый поток из пула, то время будет разное (может не быть свободных потоков, придётся ожидать их освобождения). К тому же на системах с разным количеством ядер будет использоваться разное количество потоков.

Около 15 секунд получится только на одноядерной/однопоточной системе, если поставить время сна потока 500 миллисекунд: `Thread.Sleep(500)`. А у вас там `p*500`.

---

Если вам нужна последовательность 0,1,2,3...28,29, запускайте свой код в одном потоке.

---

Кажется, я понял, как вы представляли выполнение кода: запустится 30 потоков *одновременно*, каждый будет спать некоторое количество времени, потом выведет результат. Своего рода шуточная сортировка сном - [Sleep Sort](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Sleep_sort).

Но, как я уже сказал, потоки запускаются не одновременно; в один поток будет передаваться на выполнение некоторый интервал от 0 до 30.

А главное, вызов `Thread.Sleep` не гарантирует, что поток будет спать именно указанное время. Это лишь означает указание системе разбудить поток через указанный промежуток времени.  А если в данный момент есть другие загруженные работой потоки, то до пробуждения этого может пройти существенно больше времени.